# How do I use /setblock to put down a flower pot with an Oxeye Daisy in it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been working a lot with DataValues and Entity IDs, doing mostly stuff with the `/summon` command, but i'm getting more into learning how to manipulate the world with Essentials and the Minecraft base commands. I'm trying to place a flowerpot with an Oxeye Daisy (or any flower) in it, but I can only seem to spawn in empty pots, or ones with dandelions, poppies or saplings. How do I put one down with `/setblock`?

Answer (score 1):

The command to spawn in a flower pot with an Oxeye Daisy at your feet is:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ flower_pot 0 destroy {Item:38,Data:8}
```

A flower pot's plant is stored in an associated tile entity, which is described by the {stuff in curly braces}.

An Oxeye Daisy is block 38 with a data value of 8. Block 38 encompasses all one-block flowers except for Dandelions (which are 37 for historical reasons). Check the wiki for a hopefully up-to-date [list on all the different values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Flowers).

Planting other supported items works pretty much the same. For example, an Acacia Sapling would be:

```
{Item:6,Data:4}
```

Comment: `Data` will use enumerations (i.e. the name) in 1.8, not the integer value.

Comment: @MBraedley I don't get it. So instead of 8 you would use what exactly

Comment: [Here is a list for everything](https://gist.github.com/Dinnerbone/36b4fc2c7413ffce1a05), although I don't know exactly how you would use it in this instance.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. It gives me an empty flower pot.

Comment: @PenguinatorToo Sorry, I should have tried with 1.7.9. The way you do it in that version is similar. You just have to use numeric IDs in the data tag because names don't work. They will in 1.8 though.